# yahoo_finance api throws 404. urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, python-2.7, yahoo-finance

```
$ pip install yahoo-finance
$ python
```

Then in python console,

```
>>> from yahoo_finance import Share
>>> yahoo = Share('YHOO')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/Users/ishandutta2007/virtualenvironment/googlfin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yahoo_finance/**init**.py",
>   line 178, in **init**
>       self.refresh()   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/virtualenvironment/googlfin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yahoo_finance/**init**.py",
>   line 142, in refresh
>       self.data_set = self._fetch()   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/virtualenvironment/googlfin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yahoo_finance/**init**.py",
>   line 181, in _fetch
>       data = super(Share, self)._fetch()   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/virtualenvironment/googlfin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yahoo_finance/**init**.py",
>   line 134, in _fetch
>       data = self._request(query)   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/virtualenvironment/googlfin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yahoo_finance/**init**.py",
>   line 118, in _request
>       response = yql.YQLQuery().execute(query)   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/virtualenvironment/googlfin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yahoo_finance/yql.py",
>   line 61, in execute
>       'env': DATATABLES_URL   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: This doesn't say anything about "url not found".

Comment: related: https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance/issues/139